# Is tr1 array supposed to be 16 byte aligned?

Tags: gcc, sse, tr1, memory-alignment

In "gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)" in tr1 array, I see this:

```
  value_type _M_instance[_Nm ? _Nm : 1] __attribute__((__aligned__));
```

whereas in "gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)", I see this:

```
  value_type _M_instance[_Nm ? _Nm : 1];
```

that is, it seems that tr1 arrays are no longer specified as aligned (which affects SSE code written for them). Some of our unit tests are failing in _mm_load_ps. Is there discussion of this change anywhere?

Comment: They'll be aligned for `value_type`. If you need anything beyond that, you have to add it yourself. Note that this isn't part of any standard and a pure compiler-specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification doesn't specify that `tr1::array` is 16-byte aligned. The only guarantee is that the array will be aligned properly according to the size of `value_type`. Unless the sizes of objects that you are storing in the arrays are such that `value_type` alignment is a multiple of 16 bytes, then you will not get the 128-bit alignment that you desire to use SSE instructions. If you have existing code that relies upon the fact that one compiler used 16-byte alignment for all `array` instances, then you should fix it. You're taking advantage of behavior that is in excess of what the standard defines, which is very fragile.

If you have code that relies upon a specific amount of alignment on the memory that it uses, then you should explicitly enforce that alignment when you allocate the memory; anything less is prone to errors if you change compilers or platforms. [A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564842/how-to-make-tr1array-allocate-aligned-memory) addresses how to make `tr1::array` objects use aligned memory.